# Error: 'invalid argument' when trying to upload a file to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am getting the following error while trying to upload an image to firebase storage:

```
v {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}
name: (...)
code: (...)
message: (...)
serverResponse: (...)
code_: "storage/invalid-argument"
message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."
serverResponse_: null
name_: "FirebaseError"
__proto__: Object
```

Here is my code

```html
<div>
     <h1>Upload file</h1>
     <label class="upload-group">
           <input type="file" onchange="handleFileSelect(this)" id="file">
     </label>
           <button type="button" id="uploadButton" onclick="uploadFile()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

```js
function handleFileSelect() {
  $(".upload-group").show();
  return document.getElementById('file').files[0];
};


function uploadFile() {
  var filename = handleFileSelect().name;
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/dogImages/' + filename);
  var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);
```

I have been trying for several hours to upload an image to firebase storage but, it has been unsuccessful. I postulate that the problem might with my put() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't have anything to do with security rules.  Your are passing an invalid argument to `put()`. Read the message carefully:

> Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."

You passed a string, but the API was expecting a Blob or File object. You might want to review the [documentation for uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files) for an example of how to do this correctly.